# Laravel get Images in Show User Template

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make my images table accessable from /users/show.blade.php.  I have this in my controlller..

```
public function show($id) 
{

     /* Get All CSCS Images For User */
     $my_images= Image::all(); 

    /* Get User From ID */
    $user = User::find($id);

    /* Return View */
    return view('users.show')->with('user', $user)->with('images', $my_images); 
}
```

When I try and use the $my_images variable in my template I get an undefined variable error for $my_images

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You wouldn't be using `$my_images` as you have declared `images` to be the variable within the blade therefore it would be `$images->something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function show($id) 
{

     /* Get All CSCS Images For User */
     $my_images= Image::all(); 

    /* Get User From ID */
    $user = User::find($id);

    /* Return View */
    return view('users.show',compact('user','my_images')); 
}
```

You pass `$my_images` name as `image` in your blade file for getting this error.

Comment: Beat me to it :D